# How to return a value (tuple) using the following Class script?

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup, urllib

The script below is taken [from this site](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/get-the-rottentomatoes-rating-of-a-movie/). It doesn't currently work, but I have made it work at my own computer (not currently accessible). However, what I really want is to utilize this script to **return** a tuple `(self.tomatometer, self.audience)` (Look at the function `def _process(self)`).

What I want to do is pass this script a list of movie titles (in a `for` loop) and have it return the `self.tomatometer` and `self.audience` variables to the caller.

I managed to do this, however it seems unrecommended and convoluted: Let's say I call this script `convrt.py`, this is what I've done:

```
import convrt
# this is what I'm doing, it's working, but seems weird.
convrt.RottenTomatoesRating("Movie Title Here")._process()
```

PyCharm is warning me that I'm accessing a private method of a class. I know there isn't really anything private <s>in Python and this is what is known as "name mangling"</s>, but I still think this might not be the best way to have a tuple returned from using this script?

The original script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# RottenTomatoesRating
# Laszlo Szathmary, 2011 (jabba.laci@gmail.com)

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
import urllib
import urlparse

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15'

class RottenTomatoesRating:
    # title of the movie
    title = None
    # RT URL of the movie
    url = None
    # RT tomatometer rating of the movie
    tomatometer = None
    # RT audience rating of the movie
    audience = None
    # Did we find a result?
    found = False

    # for fetching webpages
    myopener = MyOpener()
    # Should we search and take the first hit?
    search = True

    # constant
    BASE_URL = 'http://www.rottentomatoes.com'
    SEARCH_URL = '%s/search/full_search.php?search=' % BASE_URL

    def __init__(self, title, search=True):
        self.title = title
        self.search = search
        self._process()

    def _search_movie(self):
        movie_url = ""

        url = self.SEARCH_URL + self.title
        page = self.myopener.open(url)
        result = re.search(r'(/m/.*)', page.geturl())
        if result:
            # if we are redirected
            movie_url = result.group(1)
        else:
            # if we get a search list
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
            ul = soup.find('ul', {'id' : 'movie_results_ul'})
            if ul:
                div = ul.find('div', {'class' : 'media_block_content'})
                if div:
                    movie_url = div.find('a', href=True)['href']

        return urlparse.urljoin( self.BASE_URL, movie_url )

    def _process(self):
        if not self.search:
            movie = '_'.join(self.title.split())

            url = "%s/m/%s" % (self.BASE_URL, movie)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(self.myopener.open(url).read())
            if soup.find('title').contents[0] == "Page Not Found":
                url = self._search_movie()
        else:
            url = self._search_movie()

        try:
            self.url = url
            soup = BeautifulSoup( self.myopener.open(url).read() )
            self.title = soup.find('meta', {'property' : 'og:title'})['content']
            if self.title: self.found = True

            self.tomatometer = soup.find('span', {'id' : 'all-critics-meter'}).contents[0]
            self.audience = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'meter popcorn numeric '}).contents[0]

            if self.tomatometer.isdigit():
                self.tomatometer += "%"
            if self.audience.isdigit():
                self.audience += "%"
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print "Usage: %s 'Movie title'" % (sys.argv[0])
    else:
        rt = RottenTomatoesRating(sys.argv[1])
        if rt.found:
            print rt.url
            print rt.title
            print rt.tomatometer
            print rt.audience
```

Comment: *"this is what is known as "name mangling""* - no, that's **two** leading underscores, so you've have to do `ClassName._ClassName__method_name`. If your question is about the design decisions made during the development of that software, you'll have to ask whoever wrote it.

Comment: Thank you. No, that is not my question.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, have you considered [codereview.se]?

Comment: It is working after my modifications, see `convrt.RottenTomatoesRating("Movie Title Here")._process()`, I have changed this method to return a tuple. However, I'm wondering whether this way of doing things is "wrong"/unpythonic. I will take a look at Code Review, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you should be doing things this way at all.

`_process()` is prefixed with a `_` because it is supposed to be a private class method, as PyCharm warned you. This means that it should only be used within the class itself, not by you.

You're initializing an instance of the `RottenTomatoesRating` class with a movie title and then calling `._process()` on that instance. When you call the constructor of the `RottenTomatoesRating` class -- `RottenTomatoesRating(movie_title)` -- it executes the `__init__()` method of the class with your movie title passed in as the `title` parameter. The `__init__()` method also calls `self._process()`, thereby assigning values to each of `self.tomatometer` and `self.audience` if available. You can then access those values directly:

```
import convrt

ratings = convrt.RottenTomatoesRating("Movie Title Here")
tomatometer = ratings.tomatometer
audience = ratings.audience
```

Comment: Thank you. I x/posted this on Code Review and the answer there and yours have really completed the picture for me!